# How to redefine \mathbb so that it has the same effect as \mathds?

Tags: mathbb

How I could to redefine `\mathbb` so that it has the same effect as `\mathds`? I've been trying to use command line `\renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{\mathds{#1},` but this one has not had any effect.

Here's my preamble!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}%
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{longtable,rotating}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,backref=true,date=year]%
{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[toc=true,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{dsfont}%
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=latex2.dll}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2960}
%TCIDATA{Codepage=65001}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Wednesday, February 13, 2019 09:15:52}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="PrintOptions" CONTENT="8256">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%TCIDATA{Description=Documento tipo livro construido a partir da classe memoir.}
%BeginMSIPreambleData
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
%EndMSIPreambleData
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*}
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\geometry{
    left=3cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=3cm,
    bottom=2cm
}
\frenchspacing
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\input{subdoc/preambulo/new_chapter_style.tex}
\chapterstyle{daleif2modif}
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
\addbibresource{subdoc/elementos_pos_textuais/bibliografia/tese_baby_skyrme.bib}
\addbibresource{subdoc/elementos_pos_textuais/bibliografia/tese_livros.bib}
\addbibresource{subdoc/elementos_pos_textuais/bibliografia/tese_others.bib}
\addbibresource{subdoc/elementos_pos_textuais/bibliografia/tese_sigma_model_O3.bib}
\addbibresource{subdoc/elementos_pos_textuais/bibliografia/tese_Skyrme_model.bib}
\addbibresource{subdoc/elementos_pos_textuais/bibliografia/tese_teses.bib}
\addbibresource{subdoc/elementos_pos_textuais/bibliografia/tese_tqc_history.bib}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    bookmarkstype=toc,
    CJKbookmarks=true,
    bookmarksdepth=4,
    pdfstartview={FitB},
    bookmarksnumbered=true
}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    shapes,
    automata,
    backgrounds,
    petri,
    topaths
}               
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\noindent{\small{\bfseries Keywords:} #1}}
\newcommand{\palavrachave}[1]{\par\noindent{\small{\bfseries Palavras Chave:} #1}}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][\@empty]{
    \captionnamefont{\scshape}
    \changecaptionwidth
    \captionwidth{0.9\linewidth}
    \captiondelim{.\:}
    \indentcaption{0.75cm}
    \captionstyle[\centering]{}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
    \ifx \@empty#1 \caption{#2}\else \caption[#1]{#2}
}
\newcommand{\mysubcaption}[2][\@empty]{
    \subcaptionsize{\small}
    \hangsubcaption
    \subcaptionlabelfont{\rmfamily}
    \sidecapstyle{\raggedright}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
    \ifx \@empty#1 \subcaption{#2}\else \subcaption[#1]{#2}
}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{\lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,nindent=0em]{\color{black}{\textsc{#1}}}{}}
\let\mathbb\mathds
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{resu}{Result}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\loadglsentries{subdoc/elementos_pre_textuais/Siglas/Siglas.tex}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
\renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{\mathds{#1}}
\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R}$ and $mathds{R}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\mathds{}` directly?

Comment: Where exactly did you place that `\renewcommand`?

Comment: Well, in the Scientific Workplace (SWP) `\mathds{R}` it appears as a TexField, whereas `\mathbb{R}` appears as it will be compiled. If it is possible to redefine \mathbb to \mathds, then I could fool the SWP.

Comment: It might have been an idea that you mentioned you are using SWP, then  you need to be a lot more careful about where the redefinition or Stevens `\let` is placed. It has to be placed _after_ `amssymb` and `dsfont` is loaded. Hardly anyone here is familiar wit SWP, so that information is very relevant.

Comment: @daleif,I put it in the preamble, after all the packages.

Comment: `fourier` loads its stuff after the preamble, thus overwriting your redefinition, try wrapping it in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`, this delays the redefinition.

Comment: Bwsides: why are you using both the `memoir` setup for margins _and_ the `geometry` interface. I would recommend cleaning up this preamble and get a grep of what you need, and what you do not need.

Comment: @daleif, you're right! I started from an example of overleaf and, by laziness, I ended up not cleaning up the preamble. I'll see to that!

Comment: @Alexlucena It is ***very*** important to show some more details. You should also try trimming down your example, loading only what still shows the issue.

Comment: @egreg, you're probably right. I will try to improve this in the next participations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fourier` package delays its setup to the end of the preamble. So adding `\renewcommand\mathbb` in the preamble is overwritten by this delayed code.

Try using

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{\mathds{#1}}
}
```

This adds the redefinition to the delay mechanism and (hopefully) executes it after what ever is already added.

BTW: clean up your preamble, are you sure your document needs all this code? It is a good idea to add a comment above each loaded package or piece of code explaining what this does, or why it is loaded. Then it is a lot easier to see what you need and what is actually just legacy stuff you no longer need.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!
I'll clean the code as you suggested! I started with an example of a thesis that I found in the overleaf. I was afraid to go off clearing up the commands lines and so I kept.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `\let\mathbb\mathds`, though you might want to also `\let\svmathbb\mathbb` in advance of that, to save a copy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,dsfont}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{A} \mathds{A}$

\let\mathbb\mathds
$\mathbb{A} \mathds{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It works without any problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,dsfont}

\renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{\mathds{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{X}+\mathbb{Y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't load `amssymb` or `amsfonts` (or aren't sure whether other packages do), then provide the `\mathbb` command and then redefine it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,dsfont}

\providecommand{\mathbb}{} % ensure \mathbb is defined
\renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{\mathds{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{X}+\mathbb{Y}$

\end{document}
```

Some math font packages delay the definition of some commands; this is the case of `fourier`. For this you need to do the redefinition later; the following can also be used without `fourier`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fourier,dsfont}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand{\mathbb}{}% ensure \mathbb is defined
  \renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{\mathds{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{X}+\mathbb{Y}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP is using `fourier` which apparently delays its stuff.